# Connect bluetooth mouse with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

I just bought an ACer 1810T with integrated bluetooth and a Logitech Nano VX mouse.
When I use the mouse with the nano dongle it comes with, it works fine.
But of course I would like to use the integrated bluetooth device instead.

I thought it should be easy:
Enable bluetooth on the notebook, open it via the taskbar-icon and just search for devices.
Unfortunately, Windows 7 doesn't find the mouse.
As far as I can see. the mouse also has no 'connect-button' or something like this.
Of course, the mouse is on, and the dongle isn't put in the mouse (which switches the mouse completely off...)

I hope somebody now what to do, I'm a little confused about that ;)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more research I've found out that the NANO VX isn't a bluetooth mouse.
I allways believed it has to be one (because the nano reciever ist almost the same size then the little bluetooth dongles I've seen), but it seems it isn't.
Thats a pitty, but I should inform myself better before buying.